# looking for nodes based on user input in python3

Tags: python-3.x, xml

Code works well when I hardcode the nodes (e.g. node1), but not when I use user input - it always returns 0 instead of counting the numbers which are "node3". Here is the page I am using http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_678016.xml - node1 = comments, node2 = comment, node3= count. Any suggestions?

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import ssl

ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE


url = input ("Which url?\n")
node1 = input ("Enter node1- ")
node2 = input ("Enter node2- ")
node3 = input ("Enter node3- ")
count = 0

try:
    html = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
    tree = ET.fromstring(html)
    x = tree.findall(node1/node2)
    for item in x:
        c = int(item.find(node3).text)
        count = count + c
    print(count)
except:
    print("Please only input complete urls")
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting aside the user input angle, if you want "to sum up all numbers under "count"", change your xpath expression to

```
x = tree.findall('.//comment/count')
```

and then either do it the long way (which I personally prefer):

```
total = 0
for count in x:
    total += int(count.text)
```

or use list comprehensions:

```
sum([int(count.text) for count in x])
```

In either case, the output is

```
2348
```

Answer (score -1):

Found out what the mistake was - needed to concatenate strings:
x = tree.findall(node1 + "/" + node2)

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import ssl

ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE


url = input("Which url?\n")
node1 = input("Enter node1- ")
node2 = input("Enter node2- ")
node3 = input("Enter node3- ")
count = 0

try:
    html = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
    tree = ET.fromstring(html)
    x = tree.findall(node1 + "/" + node2)
    for item in x:
        count += int(item.find(node3).text)
    print(count)

except:
    print("Please only input complete urls")
```